# Two or more Web modules defined in the configuration have the same context root

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I am running tomcat server 6.0, when I tried to run any web app on this server it gives me a error saying "Two or more Web modules defined in the configuration have the same context root To start this server you will need to remove the duplicate(s)."

I am using Eclipse 3.6 helios.

How do I  remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your tomcat conf directory, edit server.xml. My guess is that in there you have two entries for teh same context. Look for two occurrences of the same line. The line will look like the following, where "someApplication" would be your context root.

```
<Context docBase="someApplication" path="/someApplication" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:someApplication"/>
```

Comment: I found that line but for different contexts, have i remove one ?

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and I clicked on "Servers" located near the console.Then I Hit the drop down arrow and deleted the module that caused the problem. For me it was the one which had my file name printed twice and on next to one of them (initialized) was written. I got rid of that one and the problem went away.

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem before. Just remove your server entity (Apache Tomcat..xxxx) in your server tab and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Eclipse will sometimes put duplicate context tags in the servers.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I got "Two or more Web modules defined in the configuration have the same context root" error . I clicked on the server tab, then deleted the tomcat server from it and the server tab remained empty. Then i re-added the new tomcat server again. Thanks for yr support

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved the issue:**

*Two or more Web modules defined in the configuration have the same context root (/WebProject). To start this server you will need to remove the duplicate(s).*

Either by Removing Frome ***`Server.xml`***

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="WebProject" path="/WebProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebProject"/>
  <Context docBase="WebProject" path="/WebProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebProject"/>
</Host>
```

OR Remove total Web-module from Modules View and Add or Remove the project by right click on `server`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a server, choose: Add and Remove and then using the Remove button remove all projects but the one you want to run

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the server tab

Select the Modules tab

You get a list of the context of the server, you have the option to delete or add one or more.